# Blender's "smoothing groups" solution (Edge Split) destroys topology. Is there an alternative solution?

Tags: modeling, topology

I was searching for how to create smoothing groups in Blender, and everybody seems to say I should use Edge Split. But this will actually create new edges, destroying the topology of the object! Is the situation really so that I cannot create 'smoothing groups' without modifying the actual topology of the object? It will be very difficult creating models for game engines or exporting to other 3d software without smoothing groups, and I don't want to destroy the topology to achieve it either..

Here, I start with a smoothed sphere:

[image: smoothed starting object]

I then apply edge split on a face, as is recommended as blender's method of doing smoothing groups:

[image: edge splitting]

This is the result. Looking good so far...:

[image: edge split result]

Then I try to select an edge loop here, but it stops on the affected area!

[image: edge loop]

When I try to move one of the edges, the reason becomes clear: Two edges have been created, completely destroying the object's topology:

[image: topology destroyed]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest you use the modifier *Edge Split* instead.
In *Edit* mode, select your edges desired to be sharp. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to bring up the *Edges* menu. Select *Mark Sharp*. Now add the *Edge Split* modifier.

[image: How to mark edges sharp]

Edges are split by the modifier. In *Edit* mode they are marked cyan. Topology is still fine:

[image: Fine topology]

Comment: Would be good if you elaborated on why modifiers are different/better.

Comment: Modifiers alter the mesh when it comes time to draw or render, leaving your mesh unaltered when you go into edit mode. Makes things a lot easier to undo or adjust.

Answer (score 12):

Since this question is old, I figured this probably relates to an older version of blender. So here's an updated answer.

The **Autosmooth** functionality was added a couple of blender versions ago (current 2.79), it enables you to specify whether edges are smooth or not without using any kind of modifier, editing, or splitting.
[image]

**Steps to use the autosmooth functionality**

> **Step 1.** Set the object to use smooth shading
>
> **Step 2.** Go to edit mode and select the edges you want to retain their sharpness
>
> **Step 3.** Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to bring up the **Edges menu**. Click on **Mark sharp**.
>
> **Step 4.** Now go to the **Mesh data** tab under the properties panel and enable **Autosmooth** under **Normals**. You can set the angle of smoothing to your liking, but I like to keep it at 180°.

The blendfile:- [image]

Comment: This is the ideal solution and should be the top answer. Marking smoothing seams without splitting the topology actually makes this method superior to smoothing groups IMO

Comment: This is the best solution currently available in Blender, so this is the best answer to this question.
However, this is not the ideal solution, as the setting is limited to angles between faces, so you can't make custom smoothing groups that are more specific. Ideally blender should have a smoothing groups functionality as most other 3D softwares have so you can set exactly the faces you want to the smoothing groups you need.