# Does anyone know how to fix this weird Faces in Blender?

Tags: modeling, faces

[image]

Flipping faces is not working, neither recalculate normlas.

Thanks for your help!

Regards!

Comment: A screenshot of your mesh in vertex select mode would be much more helpful. I'm pretty sure it's a combination of slightly bent faces and adjacent triangles. Maybe even double vertices? 

You could also upload your .blend file to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and add the given link to your question by using the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/136942/edit) below your question.

Answer (score 0):

Enter edit mode (Vertex) press 1 on top of your keyboard to filter by vertices. You´ll notice you have double vertices on the corners. Since they're together, select the corner with weird normals and hit ALT+M (merge at the middle). This will join those vertices and correct the normals.

Else, you have more vertices on the faces that you need to delete. Select a vertex, press "X and D" in that sequence.
If you find this is the answer, thank you for your consideration to vote me as the answer by clicking to the left :the icon with a check mark and upvote this answer.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but it was something related to the smoothing groups, and solved it by: "Press CTRL+E to bring up the Edges menu. Click on Mark sharp.
- Now go to the Mesh data tab under the properties panel and enable Autosmooth under Normals. You can set the angle of smoothing to your liking but I like to keep it at 180º"  as is said by Retrax here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4806/blenders-smoothing-groups-solution-edge-split-destroys-topology-is-there-a

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by going into Edit Mode, selecting all the parts of the model you need to fix, pressing W, and choosing the operation "Remove Doubles". This will automatically remove duplicate vertices that fall within a certain tiny distance of each other.